# Flawed inheritance when children classes need to include each other in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, children

Say I have a class A. Class B and class C are both children classes of A.
Would it be a flawed inheritance design if the class C needed to include B?

**edit: an example**

Say I have a parent class called Trip that has two attributes : start and end. My first inherited class (B) from A is called SimpleTrip, it has an added attribute called transport (so in total : start, end and transport). My second inherited class (C) from A is called CompoundTrip, it has two added attributes an array of SimpleTrips and a number of trips (so it total : start, end, array of SimpleTrips, number of trips). A compound trip is a "group" of simple trips, but is still a trip.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "needed to include B" - if Class C needs *everything* that Class B has, then it may be better to have Class C derived from (= child of?) Class B.

Comment: Seems safe to me, but ... Unless there are special cases I'm not considering, I don't see a need for `B` `B` will just be a `C` with one leg and the leg would not be considered a trip. This possibly eliminates inheritance entirely.

Comment: Your example seems similar to what Composite Design pattern expects.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this and try to answer "What does c.a() print" without running the program, then try and run it.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual void a() {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;   
    }
};

struct B : A {
    virtual void a() override {
        std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
    };
};

struct C : A, B {
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.a();
}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Comment: Answered a bit to soon. No diamond involved in this question. Asker has since confirmed that there is contains-a relationship not an is-a relationship between `B` and `C`.

Comment: ah didn't see! well let's leave the answer anyways in case someone else stumbles across this thread x)